# How to change my android app for different screen resolution?

Tags: android, screen, compatibility

I already developed one application which works with 480x800 screen size. But when I put my app on another mobile with 320x240 resolution, the buttons at bottom on screen is not visible(its cropped). If i drag to the screen also its not visible. Now I would like two solutions

1. If my activity has only one ImageView covering full screen of size 480x800, how can i make change my app to fit this screen for 320x240 screen size?
2. If I have a form bigger size than than the screen then I need the user to drag the screen to bottom to see the bottom screen contents. How to do that?

please help...

Comment: Could you please post your layout file?

Comment: its here - http://pastebin.com/QR7ib4fA

Comment: Do not miss the edit in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 1) you should just adapat the image size to your ImageView parent (the 'window'). Use this in your layout:

```
<ImageView 
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
  ... />
```

(Use match_parent instead of fill_parent if your developping for API 8 or higher)

For 2) you should put your controls in a [`ScrollView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html)

```
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
 <!-- Your controls here -->
</ScrollView>
```

---

**Edit** after you posted your layout:

Same advices as above apply but:

- you do not need to put a wrapping LinearLayout around your ImageView: just remove it.
- Replace the root LinearLayour of your second layout by a ScrollView.

Comment: I am developing for API 9. In my code match_parent is already there.

Comment: It's _not_. Not in the imageview.

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is to use alternative resources for different screen sizes.